# Know the number of files / directories before doing a FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs, ntfs-mft, usn

Before doing a USN journal / NTFS MFT files-enumeration with

```
while (DeviceIoControl(hDrive, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA, &med, sizeof(med), pData, sizeof(pData), &cb, NULL))
{
    // do stuff here
    med.StartFileReferenceNumber = *((DWORDLONG*) pData);    // pData contains FRN for next FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA
}
```

I'd like to know the **number of files/directories** (to "reserve" a std::vector: `v.reserve(...)` and also other reasons).

I thought about using [`FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364583(v=vs.85).aspx) before, that gives a [`USN_JOURNAL_DATA_V0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365721(v=vs.85).aspx) containing informations about the volume.

Unfortnuately `FirstUsn`, `NextUsn`, `MaxUsn` don't give this information. Even if I have 100k files on the volume, `NextUsn` can be 10 millions for example, so it doesn't give the right order of magnitude.

**How to get the number of files / directories before doing a FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA?**

Comment: Is `opendir/readdir/closedir` what you are looking for?

Comment: Which API exactly @JesperJuhl? I'm looking for a number that can be obtained in a volume in < 1 second. Just a number, that would be written somewhere in the NTFS. (I'm not looking to obtain this number via a filesystem enumeration, because I'm going to do this next in the FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA step).

Comment: possible send [`FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364568(v=vs.85).aspx) in binary search adjust `FileReferenceNumber` - this give the highest valid `FileReferenceNumber` after several iterations. the same value is returned in `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` when we reach end of enum. but this value bit more than actual number of files. for example in my test on some volume i get `f800` as this number. and count of files by `FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA` i got `d81b`, while by enumerating via `FSCTL_GET_NTFS_FILE_RECORD`- `d830`

Comment: @JesperJuhl: No Windows developer ever needs a file handling API, that doesn't support Unicode.

Comment: @RbMm According to my tests, highest FileReferenceNumber can be 5 or 10 times bigger (actual the ratio is probably somewhere between 1 and 10?) than the actual number of files in the volume, so unfortunately it won't be really useful for reserving memory space for a std::vector, etc.

Comment: may be this depend from volume

Comment: @RbMm Yes... It seems there's no "total filecount" easily obtainable from WinAPI for a volume... Strange! I really thought this info would be somewhere in USN journal / NTFS MFT, without having to enumerate all the USN records.

Comment: @IInspectable the question was not clear, so I was guessing...

Comment: I don't think this information is available.  As a general rule, Windows doesn't track information it doesn't need.  Anyway, if you use a moderately large buffer (at least a megabyte) then you won't have to loop around the call to DeviceIoControl too many times, if you allocate/extend your vector once per loop the overhead shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @HarryJohnston in the main loop, I'll fill a `std::vector<wstring>` or even a `vector<pair<wstring, DWORDLONG>>`  to store filename + parentID. That's why I need to reserve in order to reallocate this vector as least as possible. What do you call a moderately buffer (of what?) in this context? Thanks!

Comment: I mean the output buffer, `pData` in your code.  The size of that buffer determines how many entries you can receive in a single call to DeviceIoControl.  Before copying the data from `pData` into your vector, count the number of entries in the buffer, that way you only need to resize the vector once per call.

Comment: Alternatively, use a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) to prevent copying the entire controlled sequence when the container needs to grow. Assuming that operation has been identified as a bottleneck through profiling.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Guessing or not, `opendir/readdir/closedir` is not an answer to *any* Windows development question.

Comment: @IInspectable you can't deny those *do* still work on Windows (although I agree they are not the best option on that platform).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: How would you open a directory with a name containing Unicode code units, that cannot be represented in an ANSI character set?