# How to find the file modification using change Journal in windows using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to find the file or directory changes using `Change Journal` in windows.. I want a complete example code in c++.. Can anyone explain what change journal is actually and help in this.?

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off-topic for StackOverflow. The information you are looking for is available on MSDN.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry, for that.. I had gone through those but cant understand so i posted this..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the post added by Harry Johnston, i think this will the best suitable answer for you. Please find his link [How can I detect only deleted, changed, and created files on a volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421440/how-can-i-detect-only-deleted-changed-and-created-files-on-a-volume) . It contains sample code to detect changes in the journal entries. To know more about journals you need to refer msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx